# Why does `make install` fail with "gzip: stdout: No space left on device" when the disk is not full?

Tags: kernel, filesystem, compiling

I have compiled a new Kernel and set of modules base on the `linux-headers` and `linux-source` packages within Ubuntu.  The carious compilation steps have all gone well until I attempt a `make install` which fails in the following manner:

```
root@thorne-ul-dt:/usr/src/linux-source-4.4.0# make install
sh ./arch/x86/boot/install.sh 4.4.21 arch/x86/boot/bzImage \
    System.map "/boot"
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.21 /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.21
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.21 /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.21
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.21

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.21 with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
arch/x86/boot/Makefile:191: recipe for target 'install' failed
make[1]: *** [install] Error 1
arch/x86/Makefile:260: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Now everything I have read so far has suggested or ended up being down to a full filesystem.  Usually /boot or /tmp and if it is not the space it is the inodes.  So I checked my PC and all looks well to me.

```
root@thorne-ul-dt:/usr/src/linux-source-4.4.0# df -h
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                         7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs                        1.6G   19M  1.6G   2% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  1.8T  1.4T  398G  78% /
tmpfs                        7.7G  2.4M  7.7G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                        7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                    237M  100M  125M  45% /boot
/dev/sda1                    511M   12M  500M   3% /boot/efi
cgmfs                        100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs                        1.6G   64K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
root@thorne-ul-dt:/usr/src/linux-source-4.4.0# df -i
Filesystem                     Inodes    IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev                          1994762      656   1994106    1% /dev
tmpfs                         1999935     1078   1998857    1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root 121274368 17644654 103629714   15% /
tmpfs                         1999935       21   1999914    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                         1999935       13   1999922    1% /run/lock
tmpfs                         1999935       18   1999917    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                       62496      304     62192    1% /boot
/dev/sda1                           0        0         0     - /boot/efi
cgmfs                         1999935       14   1999921    1% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs                         1999935       35   1999900    1% /run/user/1000
```

Just how much space or what number of inodes does a kernel image need?

I tried doing a `purge-old-kernels` and as apt-get update && apt-get auto-remove` just in case but they did not help.

---

**What causes a `make install` of a kernel to fail with `gzip: stdout: No space left on device` when the filesystem seems to have free space and free inodes?**

Comment: My guess would be, the compiling creates a fixed size .img file for initrd, creates a filesystem in it and loop-mounts it somewhere. During build of the initrd it gets full and the process dies.

Comment: That would suggest the basic process of `apt install linux-source`, `cd /usr/src && tar xjf linux-source*.tar.bz2`.. copy headers, make menuconfig, make... `make install` is flawed then?  Am I just doing something very silly that should never happen or is it a sign something in the Ubuntu bits and bobs is a bit broken?